# Method of Differences: unable to re-write expression in usable form

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

I have been trying to prove the following using Method of Differences (the topic which the question comes under), but am unable to. There is simply no way I can re-write the expression as f(r) - f(r-1) or its equivalent. Of course, I'm unable to solve the second part as well. Would really appreciate any indirect assistance in guiding me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Hint : $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{m-1}}=\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{m-1}$$

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: Edited my post, I added m and m-1 instead of subtracting it. Now it should be correct.

Comment: How did you arrive at that? Mind sharing the intermediate step? I feel like I'm missing some concept here. @Peter

Comment: Another hint : Apply $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$ with $a=\sqrt{m}$ , $b=\sqrt{m-1}$

Comment: Oh my goodness - rationalising the denominator - of course! Thanks @Peter!